# iOS Popover Is Displaying On TextView

Tags: ios, segue, uipopover

I have implemented popovers as UIViewController presentations. I use a modal presentation style of Popover and UIPopoverPresentationController as the main view.

```
let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchTableViewController
self.searchTableViewController = popoverViewController
popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
```

My problem is that the popovers are displaying over the TextViews that they are anchored to.

Ex:

[image]

Here is how I have the TextView and the popover wired up on the story board:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the popover is pointing to the top left of this TextView? This was working fine with iOS 8 but the popovers shifted slightly in iOS9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why this was occurring but the quick solution is to move the frame where you want it. I did this with the code below:

```
let absoluteframe = patientTextField!.convertRect(patientTextField!.frame, fromView: self.scrollView)
popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(absoluteframe.minX + 60,absoluteframe.minY + 20,0,0)
```

First, you need to get the frame for the item the popup is anchored to. Then you can set the sourceRect by updating the rectangle position with their current x and y values. Hope this helps anyone with similar problems!